# How to modify the type of a Reader effect in Haskell Polysemy?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-polysemy, effect-systems

The `Reader` effect provides a `local` method which modifies the value to be read within a local scope:

```
local :: Member (Reader i) r => (i -> i) -> Sem r a -> Sem r a
```

The function passed to `local` must not change the type of the data. I would like to be able to avoid this restriction, and have an alternative to `local` which *can* modify the type of the reader value.

The obvious way to implement this is with an interpreter-style function like this:

```
local' :: (i -> j) -> Sem (Reader j ': r) a -> Sem (Reader i ': r) a
```

The problem with this approach is that it requires that the `Reader` effect is on the top of the effect stack, which may not be the case.

How can I solve this problem and modify the effect anywhere in the effect stack? If a concrete effect stack can be re-ordered, then this would also solve the problem when used in conjunction with `local'`, but I cannot find any functions to do this either.

Comment: Could you provide an example code which doesn't work? If I understand you right, it's not the problem to implement `local'`, but something related with ordering of effects?

Comment: Yes, I know how to implement `local'` but it is not general enough. If we have a concrete effect stack where `Reader` is not the first in the list, then we cannot use `local'`. For example, somewhere else in the program I might have the effect stack `'[ State (), Reader a ]`. Given a function `a -> b`, I would like to transform this stack into `'[ State (), Reader b ]`. However this is not possible with `local'`, since the effects are in the wrong order. One solution would be to re-order the effects. Another would be to write `local'` in a way such that it works with the effects in any order.

Comment: Ok I see. Is it possible to use `local' :: Member (Reader a) r => (a -> b) -> InterpreterFor (Reader b) r` as type signature? So instead of using a fixed order of effect you use `Member`, which basically says "this effect must be in the effect stack, but it doesn't matter where"

Comment: That would be more general than the original `local'`, but `InterpreterFor` still requires the effect we are interpreting (in this case `Reader b`) to be on the top of the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case. Do you have an example for that?

Comment: I was looking at the definition `type InterpreterFor e r = forall a . Sem (e : r) a -> Sem r a`, where the effect stack for the parameter requires that `e` is on the top of the stack. However, upon further thought I don't think this actually causes a problem for my use case, and so I think my problem is solved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using the following type signature doesn't require the effects to be in a fixed order:

`local' :: Member (Reader a) r => (a -> b) -> InterpreterFor (Reader b) r`